# Script to repeat "if" statement every X minutes for Y minutes and then fail if not true

Tags: bash, scripting

The 'autorep' & 'sendevent' commands are specific to Autosys but the script I have to run is as follows:

```
if autorep -g GLOBAL_VARIABLE |grep " 0 " >/dev/null
 then 
  sendevent -E SET_GLOBAL -G "YES"

 else
  sleep 2
fi
```

How do I loop this script until GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 0, or 20 minutes, whichever comes first?

I was thinking a for loop but was hoping for some guidance.

Output of autorep command:

```
Global Name                                                      Value                                                                                                Last Changed
________________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________________________________________________ ____________________
GLOBAL_VARIABLE                                                        Y                                                                                                    12/15/2020 00:00:01
```

If the Value of GLOBAL_VARIABLE is not 0 I need the script to sleep for 2 minutes and try again. The script should exit 1 if 0 isn't the Value at the end of 20 minutes.

Comment: What's the actual output of the `autorep` command?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: So what is the `" 0 "` you are looking for? You seem to just be checking if a 0 surrounded by spaces occurs anywhere in the file.

Comment: correct, the way we check for a global variable's value is this way, they are set up by us. So we create the values, the value for the variable i'll be looking at will either be 0 or N. If it is 0 I need to set it to YES so other automated processes dependent on that variable will run. At the end of the processing stream, the GV gets set to N... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a `while` loop, and add a test for the iteration count or elapsed time in addition to testing if the command worked. Assuming the command you're testing is correct, this should work in Bash or a standard shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
elapsed=0
delay=2
timeout=$(( 20 * 60 ))
success=0
while true; do
    if autorep -g GLOBAL_VARIABLE |grep " 0 " >/dev/null; then
        success=1
        break
    fi
    if [ "$elapsed" -ge "$timeout" ]; then
        break
    fi 
    sleep "$delay"
    elapsed=$(( elapsed + delay ))
done
if [ "$success" = 1 ]; then
    echo "the command succeeded after waiting "$elapsed" seconds"
else
    echo "the command never succeeded within '$elapsed' seconds"
fi
```

`delay` and `timeout` are in seconds, so 20*60 = 1200 seconds is 20 minutes.

That only takes into account the time spent sleeping, so it will be off if e.g. `autorep` takes significant time to complete. In Bash you could use `$SECONDS` to get the time since the script started instead.

Also, I suppose you know that the output from your command can't contain a `0` surrounded by spaces except in the right place, but you could do a stricter test with e.g.

```
... | grep -q "^GLOBAL_VARIABLE[[:space:]]*0 "
```

which would check the line that starts with `GLOBAL_VARIABLE` for the zero.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for I don't work with while true statements often, the autorep command returns a result in seconds, also I'm not worried about exact times, just close to 20 minutes. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I would approach it with a `while` loop in bash that tests the output *and* the elapsed time:

```
#!/bin/bash
patience=$((20 * 60))
while ! autorep -g GLOBAL_VARIABLE | grep -q " 0 "  && (( SECONDS < patience ))
do
  sleep $((2 * 60))
done
if (( SECONDS >= patience ))
then
  exit 1
else
  sendevent -E SET_GLOBAL -G "YES"
fi
```

This loops until the `autorep` command emits the `" 0 "` line or the elapsed time exceeds the patience variable. The [SECONDS variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) is one that bash sets to the number of seconds since the shell was started; here, a new shell is executing this script, so it works as a timer for us. Once that loop ends, we check to see if we ran out of time; if so, `exit 1` as required; otherwise, execute the `sendevent` command.

I explicitly expanded the timestamps for both the patience variable and the sleep command to be as clear as possible about the timeframes involved. Your original question had a conflict between "sleep 2" (two seconds) and "sleep for 2 minutes"; the code above sleeps for two minutes between tests.

Answer (score 0):

Using the GNU `timeout` command to keep track of the 20 minutes:

```bsh
if timeout 20m sh -c '
    until autorep -g GLOBAL_VARIABLE | grep -qF " 0 "; do
        sleep 120
    done'
then
    echo 'did not time out'
else
    echo 'timed out'
fi
```

The `timeout` command will exit with a non-zero exit status in the event that the 20 minutes expire.  It will exit with a zero exit status in the event that the `grep` manages to find the string that it's looking for.

Parametrizing the sleep times:

```bsh
long_sleep=20   # minutes
short_sleep=120 # seconds

if timeout "${long_sleep}m" sh -c '
    short_sleep=$1; shift
    until autorep -g GLOBAL_VARIABLE | grep -qF " 0 "; do
        sleep "$short_sleep"
    done' sh "$short_sleep"
then
    echo 'did not time out'
else
    echo 'timed out'
fi
```